# How to use vispy to generate a rolling image?

Tags: python, vispy

Some context:
I was looking into the vispy module to plot in realtime (or as close as possible to) data coming from an instrument. My attempt follow.

```
from vispy.plot import Fig
from vispy import app,scene
from vispy.visuals import TextVisual
import numpy as np
import Queue
FONT_SIZE = 14
MIN = 0
MAX = 1.1
w_size = 100
N = 5000
M = 2500
color_map = 'cubehelix'
q_size = 1000
Nb = 5

#generate (empty) initial data to fill the plot
data = np.zeros(N*M)
data = np.reshape(data, (N,M))

#setup the plot
fig = Fig(show = False,size = (16*w_size,9*w_size),bgcolor='black')
fig.title = 'my plot'
main_plot = fig[0,0].image(data = data,fg_color='w',cmap=color_map,clim=(MIN,MAX))
fig[0,0].view.camera.aspect = N/float(M) * 16./9.
title = scene.Label("someoutput", font_size=FONT_SIZE, color = 'w')
fig[0,0].grid.add_widget(title, row=0, col=4)
fig[0,0].grid[2,4].border_color = 'black'
fig[0,0].grid[2,4].bgcolor = 'black'
xlabel_title = scene.Label("x_axis [unit]", font_size=FONT_SIZE, color = 'w')
fig[0,0].grid.add_widget(xlabel_title, row=4, col=4)
ylabel_title = scene.Label("y_axis [unit]", font_size=FONT_SIZE,rotation=-90, color='w')
fig[0,0].grid.add_widget(ylabel_title, row=2, col=2)
scale = scene.ColorBarWidget(orientation='left',
             cmap=color_map,
             label='Some value',
             clim=(MIN,MAX),
             border_color = 'w',
             border_width = 1,
             label_color = 'w'
             )
fig[0,0].grid.add_widget(scale, row=2, col=6)
fig[0,0].cbar_right.width_max = \
    fig[0,0].cbar_right.width_min = 50

#fill a queue so to excude the generation time from the plotting time
q = Queue.Queue()
for i in range(q_size):
    new_data = (np.abs(0.5*np.random.randn(Nb*M)[:])).astype('float32')
    new_data = np.reshape(new_data, (Nb,M))
    q.put(new_data[:])

#update function
def update(ev):
    global main_plot, q, data, Nb,M,fig,index            


   #acquire
    new_data = q.get()

    #roll the plot data
    data[Nb:, :] = data[:-Nb, :]
    data[:Nb,:] = new_data

    #recycle the new data
    q.put(new_data)

    #update the plot
    main_plot.set_data(data)
    main_plot.update()



# setup timer
interv = 0.01
timer = app.Timer(interval = interv)
timer.connect(update)
timer.start(interval = interv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fig.show(run=True)
    app.run()
```

This code currently works but it's much slower than the data rate. In the vispy gallery, as well as in some examples, I saw much more points being plotted and updated. I think that the main problem is that I completely set each time all the data of the plot instead of shifting them and inserting new points.

I also had a look at this example:
https://github.com/vispy/vispy/blob/master/examples/demo/scene/oscilloscope.py

However I don't know how to generalize the update function that rolls the data (I have no knowledge of OpenGL) and I cannot use the example as is because I need a quantitative color scale (that seems well implemented in vispy.plot).

The question:
Is there a way to write a function that rolls the data of a plot generated with the vispy.plot class?

Thanks.